# Restrict access to admin-post.php

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, redirect

I have a form that hooks into `admin_post_nopriv`, after this hook has completed, the user is logged in. Now, there is a bug that occurs when the user has this form open in two separate tabs, completes the first form and posts it, and then completes the second form and posts it.

It simply redirects to `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php` showing a blank page. This is because after the user has been automatically logged in, the `admin_post_nopriv` hook no longer works.

How can I make sure that no one is able to access `admin-post.php` directly like this? Ideally, I would just redirect people away from that URL unless it's being called by POST action.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that disabling admin-post.php is a good idea. Such solution may break WP, some plugins and themes.

But there is another, much simpler solution. Just add your action for admin_post (without nopriv) and process it properly - so if it’s a login action and user is already logged in, redirect him to proper url...

Comment: That was the second option I was thinking about. It seems rather counter-intuitive though, especially considering the role that these two `admin_post` hooks have. It might as well have been one hook if I'm going to have to use them both everywhere.

Comment: It’s not counter intuitive. If you write your custom login form, you always have to process the case when user is already logged in - it’s a standard edge case. You can’t restrict such requests...